# how to add a before expanding event to the wpf treeview without using threads

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am trying to add a progress bar which will be displayed when an expanding item is clicked in a tree view. This bar should be displayed right after the item is clicked and made invisible once the item is expanded. I tried to add a handler for this event, that i found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/246c3eb0-2e93-4a45-9ffc-b2e3632b8925)
, but it's not working.

i'm using it like this:

```
 treeItemsToAdd = new MyTreeViewItem();
 treeItemsToAdd.Expanding += treeItemsToAdd_Expanding;
```

i cant figure out why this isn't working... the treeItemsToAdd_Expanding event fires only after the item is expanded

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to override OnExpanded virtual method and raise Expanding event before its default implementation.

```
public class MyTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
{
        public static readonly RoutedEvent CollapsingEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Collapsing",
             RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
             typeof(MyTreeViewItem));

    public static readonly RoutedEvent ExpandingEvent =
             EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Expanding",
             RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
             typeof(MyTreeViewItem));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Collapsing
    {
        add { AddHandler(CollapsingEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(CollapsingEvent, value); }
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler Expanding
    {
        add { AddHandler(ExpandingEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ExpandingEvent, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnExpanded(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnExpanding(new RoutedEventArgs(ExpandingEvent, this));
        base.OnExpanded(e);
    }

    protected override void OnCollapsed(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnCollapsing(new RoutedEventArgs(CollapsingEvent, this));
        base.OnCollapsed(e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollapsing(RoutedEventArgs e) { RaiseEvent(e); }
    protected virtual void OnExpanding(RoutedEventArgs e) { RaiseEvent(e); }
}
```

Comment: Just pasting code without explaining how it works or how to implement it is very bad practice, regardless if it works or not.
There will be people that will come up to this scratching their heads how they're supposed to use this, or even people that despite finding out how to implement it not knowing how it works.